# ListView Adapter always removes the last row

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

So for example when I run `ListViewAdapter.remove(ListViewAdapter.getItem(position))` when it renders it always rerenders by deleting the last row, even though the position parameter is always different. If I have 4 rows and i try to delete the third row, the position is 3, but it doesn't matter, it deletes the last row.
I have to reopen the activity in order to see the correct result? Why is that?

```
    private ListView videoList;
    private VideoListAdapter videoListAdapter;
```

My methods look something like this

```
videoList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                parentViewPosition = position;

                view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onButtonCliCk(view);
                makeButtonInvisible(view);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

```
    public void deleteElement(final String fileName) {
        folderPath.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                for (StorageReference storageReference : listResult.getItems()) {
                    if (storageReference.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                        storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Element sters cu succes",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                updateListViewAdapter(parentViewPosition);

                                deleteDatabaseDownloadReference(mDatabase);
                                uploadAllDownloadURIS();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("STERGEREA A ESUAT");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my adapter

```
package com.example.navigation.ViewVideos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.navigation.R;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class VideoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StorageReference> {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoListAdapter";

    private Context mContext;

    private int mResource;

    public VideoListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<StorageReference> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        if (vi == null) {
            String folderName = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "folderName must not be null").getName();
            String bucket = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "bucket must not be null").getBucket();
            String path = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getPath();
            vi = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.folderName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView);
            holder.folderName.setText(folderName);

            holder.bucket = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView2);
            holder.bucket.setText(bucket);

            holder.path = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView3);
            holder.path.setText(path);


        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        return vi;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView folderName;
        private TextView bucket;
        private TextView path;
    }

}
```

And this is the method I call in order to update the ListView

```
   public void updateListViewAdapter(int parentViewPosition){
        videoListAdapter.remove(videoListAdapter.getItem(parentViewPosition));
        videoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: "If I have 4 rows and i try to delete the third row, the position is 3, but it doesn't matter, it deletes the last row."  Since arrays and lists are zero-indexed, a position of 3 is the fourth item.

Comment: I am aware they're zero-indexed, that was just an example. If I try to delete the 2nd row and there are 5 rows it also deletes the last row.

Comment: I did another test. If I try to delete the last row and then try to delete any other row it throws  ```E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navigation, PID: 23286
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4``` 

For this particular example I have 5 rows, but as you can see it always goes for the last row for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (vi == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        vi = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.folderName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView);
        holder.bucket = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView2);
        holder.path = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView3);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    String folderName = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "folderName must not be null").getName();
    String bucket = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "bucket must not be null").getBucket();
    String path = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getPath();
    holder.folderName.setText(folderName);
    holder.bucket.setText(bucket);
    holder.path.setText(path);

    return vi;
}
```

Without ViewHolder:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
}

TextView folderName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView);
TextView bucket = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView2);
TextView path = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoTextView3);

String folderName = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "folderName must not be null").getName();
String bucket = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position), "bucket must not be null").getBucket();
String path = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getPath();
folderName.setText(folderName);
bucket.setText(bucket);
path.setText(path);

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: ```E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navigation, PID: 7557
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.example.navigation.ViewVideos.VideoListAdapter$ViewHolder.folderName' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Try move `vi.setTag(holder);` to just before `return vi;` and see if that fix the NPE issue. Otherwise try the getView() without ViewHolder.